# From dynamic end point WSDL to static wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl

I used a dynamic end point wsdl (wsdl via http) to generate the client side. This works fine.

Is it possible to generate a static wsdl from the http link of dynamic wsdl?

The problem is that the dynamic wsdl is accessible only from one machine.

I would like to developp the client side on another pc.

Thank you.

Comment: what build system do you use?

Comment: download wsdl and put it into source control, setup maven to generate Java classes from it using maven plugin (I use CXF plugin) and you are done

Comment: the problem is that when I use the remote http wsdl the client side is generated correctly but when using the local copy I have an exception. The local copy is created as floows : I copy the whole browser content of the wsdl? is it the correct way to get a local copy of wsdl? And there are import tags + a specific namespace which is not available in the local copy.

Comment: do not copy paste content, it is better to use `Save as...` context menu of your browser

Comment: And there are import tags + a specific namespace which is not available in the local copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download WSDL and put it into source control, setup Maven to generate Java classes from it using maven plugin (I use CXF plugin) and you are done.

In order to download all imported XSDs you can use one of the available tools, please refer to these SO questions: [Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667880/simple-tool-to-download-all-imported-included-wsdls-and-schemas), [Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286657/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-all-of-the-wsdl-files-exposed-by-a-wcf-service)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please telle me how to use SoapUI to download the WSDL and it's dependencies (imports& namespaces etc)?

Comment: It's ok now, it's in the WSDL content tab. Thank you.